# "unable to load Private Key" error when try to open openssl private key file on mac

Tags: meteor, openssl

How can I open a private key created on a linux server from a Mac ?

Some context : I'm using a local script called `mup` to deploy a Meteor app which requires the openssl private key.
I created the openssl private key on a linux ubuntu server I'm deploying to.
I am deploying from my Mac OS 10.9.5.

The mup script throws this error : 

`-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Trying to initialize SSL contexts with your certificatesError loading rsa private key
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------`

So, the local mac can't open or access the private key. 
This command works on the ubuntu server where the key was created : 

 `openssl rsa -in private-key.nopass.key -check`

However, If I run that same command on my local Mac on the same file ( which I copied and pasted from the terminal into Sublime text, with normal settings. ) ,  the local Mac throws this error :

`unable to load Private Key
... routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

So, I'm assuming the `mup` error has something to do with this.
On the local mac the openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016.`
On the remote linux server  the openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so, the good folks at namecheap.com support helped me with this question.  Turns out I was missing one dash!! haha.

This (4 dashes):

```
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Should have been this (5 dashes):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The takeaway is count your dashes when manually copying/pasting these files!  It's far too easy to mistake four dashes for five.

Comment: Also, I realized I have a bug in my mac terminal theme, when I view a file in nano, it doesn't display the first character of the file for some reason.

Comment: Jezz so simple - took me good 1 hour before i found this solution